# What is the meaning of BAT○ in btop++?

Tags: monitoring, btop

On top (of the default layout) I have the CPU graph box. The title line of this box says on the left : "cpu", "menu", "preset 0", and on the right : `BAT○` 98%, and 2000ms.
Everything is self-explanatory, except BAT○. Clicking it does nothing. I noticed BAT and ○ don't have the same font.

An extensive search of the web and of their github returned nothing. There is no man page. The included help is not searchable.
After extensive searching, I suspect this may be related to the bat command (alternative to cat), or this may be the name of the font in use, maybe specific to my system.

btop aka btop++ is an alternative to htop

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It isn’t a display glitch, nor is it “BAT0”.

“BAT” stands for “battery”, and the circle (○) following that indicates that the battery charge status is unknown (this is independent of the battery charge level, which is indicated by the meter following “BAT”). Other possible values are an arrow-head pointing up (▲) if the battery is charging, down (▼) if it’s discharging, and a filled square (■) if it’s full.

See [the source code](https://github.com/aristocratos/btop/blob/9edbf27f1b6d5844a97325fcda732762ba086a99/src/btop_draw.cpp#L610) for details; as you say this doesn’t seem to be documented.

Comment: oh, thanks. I was mistaken because after maybe 30 minutes of searching, I searched for "BAT1", and that's how I at least understood it was BAT for battery. Thanks for explaining the round o.

Comment: Yes, in other contexts “BAT0” makes sense, but not in `btop` ;-).

Answer (score 1):

Found it. It's just a display glitch. It's not `BATo` or `BAT o`, it's BAT0 or BAT 0. It's just the battery level.